# Creating a method accessible from all controllers

Tags: php, codeigniter, static, hmvc

I need to make a model method which can be accessed from all other controllers, regardless of parents and modules.

I'm using CodeIgniter and HMVC patterns, if that have anything to say.

What I am looking for is identical to `static` classes/methods in `Java`

Edit: I need this to check wether a user is online or not. Putting it in the `User Model` will not suffice, as I need to check if a user is online in plenty other modules

Comment: In [tag:codeigniter] is there something like app_model in CakePHP?

Comment: That sounds interesting and indeed a useful feature. However as far as I'm aware, there is no such feature in `CodeIgniter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class User
{
    public static function is_online($user) { }
}

$online = User::is_online($user);
```

Comment: How would I access this from a controller?